# Importing a CSV file via PHPmyadmin: file not found or access denied

Tags: mysql, file-io, phpmyadmin, load

I am using PhpMyAdmin 2.6.2 on my domain hosting server. I have a table and I want to import data into it from a small, CSV-format file. (It's a pilot to see how it works.)

SQL query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/shoelinks.csv' INTO TABLE `shoelinks` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

MySQL said:

```
#2 - File 'c:\shoelinks.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

I tried importing the CSV file from various different directories (e.g. 
`MySql/Data`, `PHPmyAdmin/import`, etc.). But I still get the same "file not found" problem.

When I use the SQL without the `LOCAL`, this is what I get; SQL query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\\Websites\\uploadtemp\\php7BA8.tmp' INTO TABLE `shoelinks` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

MySQL said:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'rs1-sl9'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I am not supposed to have any privileges problem as I logged into phpmyadmin, and I am the DB admin.

What can I do to be able to import the data file?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem.  CPanel requires granting file privileges in order to run this query.  Contact your hosting support on how to do that.

FYI, if you are using a GoDaddy shared hosting solution, this will not be allowed.